# Using a special API call

Tags: node.js

I wanted to checkout the GoEuro-Api, but I get:

> GoEuroAPI is not a constructor

You can give it a try here:

https://runkit.com/npm/goeuro-api

My code:

```
var GoEuroAPI = require("goeuro-api");

const GoEuroClient = new GoEuroAPI();

var params = {
    "searchOptions": {
        "departurePosition": { "id": 376217 },
        "arrivalPosition": { "id": 377001 },
        "travelModes": ["Flight", "Train", "Bus"],
        "departureDate": "2017-04-08",
        "returnDate": null,
        "passengers": [{ "age": 12 }],
        "userInfo": {
            "identifier": "0.dj87mh4f039",
            "domain": ".com", "locale": "en", "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "abTestParameters": []
    }
};

// Init the search and get flights, trains and buses.
GoEuroClient.search(params)
  .then((response) => {
      GoEuroClient.flights()
        .then(flights => console.log(flights));

      GoEuroClient.trains()
        .then(trains => console.log(trains));

      GoEuroClient.buses()
        .then(buses => console.log(buses));
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

// Get buses by search_id
GoEuroClient
  .buses({ search_id: id })
  .then(buses => console.log(buses))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

What is wrong here, what should it be instead ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Nidhin David using the `import` instead I get an error ...

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/goeuro-api | https://github.com/evgenTraytyak/goeuro-api

Comment: babel would fix said error.

Answer (score 2):

while only importing `goeuro-api`

```
var GoEuroAPI = require("goeuro-api");
```

It exposes an object `{ default: [Function: GoEuroAPI] }`

Instead to use the Constructor Function

Do

```
var GoEuroAPI = require("goeuro-api").default; // exposes a function 
                                               // [Function: GoEuroAPI]

const GoEuroClient = new GoEuroAPI();
```

Comment: great article on modules http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: I think this library he is using is full of bugs!

Comment: @NidhinDavid Yes and It might be the their own  custom package, they are working on.